# How do i run inner join and make variables which show dynamic page in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have 6 tables in database `movie_info`, `star_info`, `classification_info`, `director_info`, 
`genre_info`, `studio_info`.

where `star_info`, `classification_info`, `director_info`, `genre_info`, `studio_info` are main tables which hold all the information for `movies-star`, Classification, director of movies and movies table only contain the FK of those tables.

now I wants to do is Show in my php page all the movies which stored in my movie_info table with Directors, stars, genre... FK  from 5 above tables.
note that movie_info table only has ID field of Direcor and stars not the name so i have run the inner join to get name.

```
sql = mysql_quary("
    SELECT 
      movie_info.movie_id, movie_info.movie_name, movie_info.tagline, movie_info.plot, star_info.star_name 
    FROM movie_info 
    INNER JOIN star_info 
      ON movie_info.star_id = star_info.id
")
```

Now my question is how can i Use this names and show to php page, I mean I will be having Five different queries (Director, Gener, Classification) which will need to get name from their own table and come back to show their name instead of their FK which has been stored in `movie_info` table.

Comment: From your question it looks like that you already solved your problem. Your query does already return the name of the star, doesn't it?

Comment: yes I got it now , but there is one more issue is since i have four tables which will get the name, how i run multiple INEER JOIN Query please help.

Comment: Just add another INNER JOIN clause after the one you have for the next table. See that it works and add the next one until you have all five.

Comment: Actually there is a manual that explains how to run multiple inner joins. You should read the section carefully and afterwards you know how to do it or you know where you can read how to do it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/

Answer (score 0):

To run multiple inner joins its really easy, here is the basic structure of how its done.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.value1 comp[=, <, >, <=, >=] table2.value1 INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.value2 comp[=, <, >, <=, >=] table3.value1
```

So that should solve your problem.

Comment: i got this errormysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,

Comment: Please paste your complete code for clearly solving your problem